# Exclude one project from portfolio analysis

Tags: 2013, project-server

I have dozen of projects on our project web app, from those projects I want to exclude one project from portfolio so data from it won't be included in reports.

If anybody can explain if this is plausible and how to manage it?

*Additional info:*
While I was wandering around PWA settings I came up to Portfolio analyses. I saw there I can create new Portfolio analyses and in it I could exclude whichever project I want. But I am not sure if this is correct way to do what I want nor I know how to make it to be default portfolio analyses.

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved it.

Open **PWA settings** > bellow **Enterprise Data** choose **Resource Center** > at the left bar (Current navigation), bellow **Strategy** choose **Portfolio Analysis**.

Click on **New** button, go through the new analyses creator.

Detailed explanation I found [here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh768873(v=office.14).aspx)